# How to access the init variable obtained from parent class into child method in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, init

I have a parent class and a child class where the child class inherits the init variables from the parent class using super() or Patent function. But, I am unable to access these variables inside the method of the child. How to obtain that? Here is the below code.

```
class Parent:

   def __init__(self, item, model):
          self.item = item
          self.model = model

class child(Parent):
   
   def __init__(self, item, model):
       Parent.__init__(self, item, model)

       print(item)  # I am able to get this value

   def example(self): 

       value = self.item * 10 # This item is not able to access and throughs an error.

       print(value)
```

Calling child method:

```
child.example()
```

Error:

```
'child' object has no attribute 'item'
```

How to get the item variable from the parent class into the method of child class?

Comment: I actually _don't_ get this error with your code. Calling `c = child(10, 'whatever')` and `c.example()` prints out `10` and `100`, as expected. Tested with Python 3.9.6 64-bit on Windows 10.

Comment: Wouldn't that _always_ crash regardless? You need to pass an instance of `child` as a parameter (which makes it work as expected) or it will crash due to missing `self`. Where and how exactly are you calling `child.example()` that results in the error you mentioned?

Comment: generally you should do `super().__init__(item, model)` instead of `Parent.__init__(self, item, model)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how you are calling `example()`:

```
child.example()
```

You're calling the `example()` method of the *`child` class itself*; you are not calling that method on an *instance* of `child`. The class itself does not have the `self.item` or `self.model` properties. Those are set in the constructor (`__init__()`). To call the contstructor you have to instantiate a new instance of the `child` object:

```
c = child(10, 'blah')
```

Now that `c` is an instance of `child`, you can call `example()` on the instance now:

```
c.example()
#output: 10
```

Remember, this works because `c` is a reference to a *specific instance* of the `child` class, which you deliberately created previously. `child` refers to the *class itself*; it will not have any `self` instance variables, because a class is just a class, its constructor hasn't run because it only runs when you instantiate a class, not when you deal with the class itself.

One way to avoid this issue is to adhere to the naming standards in Python. Classes always should be `CamelCase`, and variables should all be `snake_case`. That way, you can easily tell that `child.what_ever()` is calling a method on an instance of a class, and that `Child.blah_blah()` is calling a class method.

For a full list of Python naming conventions, see here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Comment: This is also a good reason to follow standard naming convention for classes, i.e. CamelCase... currently `child` looks like a variable, i.e. an instance, which is confusing... especially when `Parent` is named as expected